# php mysql multi-user website file structure

Tags: php

I'm creating multi-user php website with blog module.
Which have 3 user types,
And I'm handling file structure like this,

```html
assets    //which have css,js and image
-img
-styles
-script

pages
-login
-registration
-index

Includes  //common use files
-header
-navigation
-footer
-user-authentication
-scripts

actions //perform action related files
-functions
-all other php proccessing files.

admin  //admin user role
-index
-services
-blog
  -add/edit/delete
-users
 -add/edit/delete

officers  //2nd user role
-index
-blog
  -add/edit/delete
-edit profile
-some other files related to the officer role. 

users    //3rd user role
-index
-edit profile
-some other files related to the user role.
```

In admin role blog, duplicated in officers too
in officers role edit profile, duplicated in users too.

I'm feel like its like a mess. is there any good practice to make file more usable way?

Answer (score -2):

The file structure for a PHP MySQL multi-user website can vary based on the specific architecture and design patterns you choose. However, I can provide a basic example structure that incorporates separation of concerns and modularity:

```
-

 /public_html (or your web server's root directory)
  - /css               // CSS files
  - /js                // JavaScript files
  - /images            // Image files
  - index.php          // Entry point for the website

- /includes            // PHP files for reusable code
  - config.php         // Database configuration
  - functions.php      // General helper functions
  - header.php         // Header template
  - footer.php         // Footer template

- /pages               // Individual page files
  - /auth              // Authentication-related pages
    - login.php        // Login page
    - register.php     // Registration page
    - forgot_password.php // Password recovery page
  - /dashboard         // User dashboard pages
    - profile.php      // User profile page
    - settings.php     // User settings page
    - ...
  - /admin             // Admin panel pages
    - manage_users.php // Page to manage users (admin-only)
    - manage_posts.php // Page to manage posts (admin-only)
    - ...
  - error.php          // Error pages (404, 500, etc.)
  - home.php           // Homepage

- /classes             // Object-oriented PHP classes
  - User.php           // User class
  - Database.php       // Database connection class
  - ...

- /templates           // HTML templates (optional)
  - /auth              // Templates for authentication pages
    - login.html       // Login form template
    - register.html    // Registration form template
  - /dashboard         // Templates for dashboard pages
    - profile.html     // User profile template
    - settings.html    // User settings template
    - ...

- /vendor              // Third-party libraries (e.g., Composer packages)

- /uploads             // Directory to store uploaded files
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, however what about the user types. each user type has to have different dashboard when login. can you suggest me how to manage that?

also, where should i store the php action files?
because i have separate file for user authentication, some other functions.